# How to connect wired and wireless router with wireless shutting off at night

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

I want to set up a home network where a wired (no wireless) router is plugged into the modem, and the wireless router is plugged into the wired router.

At first I was going to get a switch to set up before the router, but that won't work because only one IP will come from the ISP. But if the first router functions as a wired router, and the second router functions as an access point, then I think it should work.

This way I can shut off wireless at night by cutting the power to the wireless router. I currently do that already, but I have something I need to run 24/7 with a wired connection, so I want to use a separate router for that.

Basically:

> MODEM
>       ||
>  WIRED ROUTER       [Power Outlet Timer]
>      ||              ||                  |
> 24/7 PC   WIRELESS ROUTER
>                      ||
>                  OTHER DEVICES

Will this cause any issues, is there anything I need to know?

Comment: It should work.

Comment: I agree it should work. I do not turn off my wireless router (also attached to my wired router). If I did, cell phones would switch to cellular and may update apps overnight. Consider just leaving wireless on so your devices stay connected to wireless instead of cellular

Comment: Huh? You don't know how to turn OFF auto update apps in the play store? Not to mention turn OFF your phone's auto-switching to mobile? I keep mobile AND wifi OFF 24/7 EXCEPT WHEN USING IT.


I WILL NOT BE LEAVING ON EMF WIFI RADIATION 24/7!!


Since disabling wifi at night, my sleep has been MUCH better.

Comment: In face I'm considering disabling ALL wireless internet for 22 hours per day, only allowing me to use internet for 2 hours per day besides work for which my pc is hard wired with ethernet.